# Confusion with .then() chaining

Tags: javascript, next.js, promise

I've been trying to understand how Promises/then-ables work for awhile now.
I'm working with NextJS.

Trying to chain together to do the following:

1. Get data from API
2. Save the data
3. Modify the data to create component
   (And not infinite loop)

I can't get the proper data to do step #3.
I've tried various things but am stuck on this step.

I'm using useEffect because of this (though I'm sure there's other ways to do it):
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/client-side

```js
export default function Survey() {
  const [dataDB, setDataDB] = useState('');
  let roles;

  function createCards(rolesArr) {

    let role1 = tabs.find(x => x.id == rolesArr[0])
    let role2 = tabs.find(x => x.id == rolesArr[1])
    let role3 = tabs.find(x => x.id == rolesArr[2])

    // the above is null
    // the below is also null:
    //     let role1 = tabs.find(x => x.id == dataDB[0])

    roles.push(role1)
    roles.push(role2); 
    roles.push(role3); // component will map over these 3
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('example.com/api')
      .then((response) => response.json()) // 1. Gets an array like [0, 3, 5]
      .then((data) => {
        setData(dataDB) // 2. Using hook to setData, will store in database later
      }
     .then((rolesArr) => createCards(rolesArr)) // 3. Modify data for component
    })
  )  

  return ( 
    { 
      roles.map((path) => (
        <Card key={path.id}>
          <Text>{path.title}</Text>
        </Card>
      ))
    } 
  )
}
```

Comment: Your `.then()` callback that does `setData()` does not return anything, so the next `.then()` callback gets `undefined` for `rolesArr`.

Comment: You aren't returning a value from your second step. Change that to return the value that step 3 is expecting. i.e. `.then((data) => { setData(dataDB); return data; }`

Comment: You're also missing a `)` after your second step but i'm assuming that's just a typo.

Comment: Don't use braces in arrow functions needlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a *lot* of problems here.

## roles is undefined

`let roles;` creates a variable and sets its value to `undefined`.

The next time you touch it (here: `roles.map((path) => (`) you are trying to treat it as an array.

This will error.

You need to make it an array when you define it.

## a typo

> ```
> .then((data) => {
>         setData(dataDB) // 2. Using hook to setData, will store in database later
>       }
> ```

You are missing a `)` from the end of there

## `rolesArr` is `undefined`

The return value of:

> ```
> .then((data) => {
>         setData(dataDB) // 2. Using hook to setData, will store in database later
>       }
> ```

… is `undefined` because you have no `return` statement, so the next `then()` callback in the chain gets passed `undefined`.

**However** you aren't doing anything that requires you to create a new promise there, so there's no point in using an extra `then`, just do everything you want to do with the data in the function you already have.

```
  .then((data) => {
    setData(dataDB);
    createCards(dataDB);
  });
```

## createCards modifies an array that doesn't exist and that nothing uses

> ```
>  roles.push(role1)
>  roles.push(role2); 
>  roles.push(role3); // component will map over these 3
> ```

You have the same problem here that you did earlier; `roles` isn't an array, it is `undefined`.

What's more, because `createCards` is called asynchronously, this code will run **after** `roles.map((path) => (` so nothing is going to pay attention to the mutation anyway.

Don't mutate the non-existent array. Create a new one and **store it in a state**. Setting a state will trigger a re-render so the component will pull the array out of the state storage and have some values to iterate over.

Typically you would want to do something like:

```
const [roles, setRoles] = useState(null);

function createCards(rolesArr) {
    // etc
    setRoles([role1, role2, role3]);
}

// etc

if (roles === null) {
    return <p>Loading</p>;
}

return roles.map(etc etc);
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the `.then()`, you need to return the resulting value from the previous callback function if you want to chain one or more `.then()`. As an example:

```js
fetchData()
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.json())
    return response.json()
  }).then((values) => {
    console.log(values)
    return values.filter((value) => value > 0)
  }).then((positiveValues) => {
    console.log(positiveValues)
    return positiveValues;
  })
```

This example will print the `response.json()` and return it as a value to be used as an argument on the next `.then()` callback.

For your case, return the value inside the second callback like this:

```js
    fetch('example.com/api')
      .then((response) => response.json()) // 1. Gets an array like [0, 3, 5]
      .then((data) => {
        setData(dataDB) // 2. Using hook to setData, will store in database later
        return dataDB;
      }).then((rolesArr) => createCards(rolesArr)) // 3. Modify data for component
    })
```